# react navigation issue in react-native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am a newbie at react-native and I am facing some issues in the react-native app, after installing 'react-navigation', everything is mentioned in the images. Hope you can help me. Have a good day.

[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbyQb.png)

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXn4y.png)

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOutk.png)

[Terminal-issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg2Ju.png)

[Node-cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpHRy.png)

Comment: Your MainActivity.java file is incorrect. `package com.awesomeproject` should be the first line.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** install @react-navigation/stack by
`npm install @react-navigation/stack`
using console(console must be opened in your project main directory).

Choose one:

1. If you are using bare React-Native project install react-gesture-handler using `npm install react-native-gesture-handler`.
2. If you are using expo managed project(e.g you created project using npx expo init) - use
   `npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler`.

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

After successfull install please restart your metro/expo server.

Comment: thanks my friend for your answering, but I am facing the same error even after doing these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createNativeStackNavigator` from `native-stack` instead.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

...

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
...
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

See [Installing the native stack navigator library](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation#installing-the-native-stack-navigator-library) for details.